# JavaScript 100 Doors

Tags: javascript

New JavaScript programmer here. I'm trying to figure out a practice problem but don't know where I went wrong with my code.

The question: You have 100 doors in a row that are all initially closed. You make 100 passes by the doors. The first time through, you visit every door and toggle the door (if the door is closed, you open it; if it is open, you close it). The second time you only visit every 2nd door (door #2, #4, #6, ...). The third time, every 3rd door (door #3, #6, #9, ...), etc, until you only visit the 100th door.

Question: What state are the doors in after the last pass? Which are open, which are closed?

**EDIT**
For the record this isn't a homework problem... I'm trying to teach myself Javascript, and I found the question from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/100_doors

My code:

```
var doors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100;  i++) {
  doors[i] = "Closed";
}

for (var j = 1; j <= 100; j++) { // j is what you're dividing by
  for (var k = 0; k < 100; k++) { //0 is the first door b/c of arrays
    if (doors[k] % j === 0) {
      toggle(k);
    }
    else {}
  } 
}

for (var counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
  console.log("Door " + (counter + 1) + " is " + doors[counter]);
}

function toggle(value) {
  if (doors[value] === "Open") {
    doors[value] = "Closed";
  }
  else {
    doors[value] = "Open";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...

Comment: Lol I'm not in school; trying to teach myself JavaScript. The problem is that all of them are reported closed.

Comment: just google it, so many answers.... https://www.google.com/search?q=You+have+100+doors+in+a+row+that+are+all+initially+closed.+You+make+100+passes+by+the+doors.+The+first+time+through%2C+you+visit+every+door+and+to&oq=You+have+100+doors+in+a+row+that+are+all+initially+closed.+You+make+100+passes+by+the+doors.+The+first+time+through%2C+you+visit+every+door+and+to&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: But I want to learn what I'm doing wrong, not what other people are doing right...

Comment: @Yatrix and others: It does not matter if it is a homework problem. It is a well-asked question (well, almost: you'd want to include why you don't think it's working). If you suspect the problem is educational, you try to answer it in such a way to maximise educational value. [Meta: How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @Amadan never did I take issue with it being a homework question or not. I simply stated it sounded like one.

Comment: @Yatrix: I saw the question being downvoted approximately in the same measure your comment was upvoted. While you yourself might not have done so, I put the clarification in to deter anyone else from taking the content of your comment as grounds for downvoting the question.

Comment: @Amadan you know what they say about assuming... =)

Comment: @Yatrix: I explicitly said I do not assume you downvoted for that reason, only that certain people did, and more might in the future.

Comment: @Amadan I don't see where you explicitly said that, but cool by me. Let's just stop talking now. 'Night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doors[k] % j` is nonsense (`"Closed" % 1`).

`k % j == 0` will be true for the 0-th door, always. Use `(k + 1) % j` to trigger 2nd, 5th, 8th (i.e. #3, #6, #9 in English)... when `j` is `3`.

While it's not an error, it would be easier if you had just Boolean values in the array: say, `false` for closed, `true` for open. Then toggling is just `doors[value] = !doors[value]`. Transform to strings at output, as `"Closed"` and `"Open"` are only relevant to humans.

Comment: Beat me to it by just seconds :)

Comment: Thank you for that catch! I also get why k % j wouldn't work for 0, but I don't understand why I'd use (k + 1) % j.

Comment: Because you want every door that cleanly divides by `j` in *English*; when translated to computerese, it's off by one: #3 is actually `j == 2`, #6 is actually `j == 5`... so when you add one to the indices, you get numbers you want (that divide cleanly by `j`). E.g. when `j == 3` and `j == 5`, `(5 + 1) % 3` is `0`, toggling your door #6.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem. I think you dont need "closed" or "open". Instead try to use booleans(true or false) instead.

```js
function getFinalOpenedDoors(numDoors) {
const array=[];
for(let i=1; i<101;i++){
  array[i]=false
}
let turn=1
while(turn<=100){
  for(let i=turn; i<101;i++){
    if(i%turn===0){
    array[i]=!array[i]
    }
  }
  turn=turn+1
}

const container=[]

for(let j=0;j<array.length;j++){
  if(array[j]===true)
  container.push(j)
}

return container

}

getFinalOpenedDoors(100)
```